# Mongodb: aggregate values on array of subdocuments

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have collection of documents:

```
{
    "_id": ObjectId("55dc62647cda24224372e308"),
    "last_modified": ISODate("2015-07-01T15:57:26.874Z"),
    "services": [
        {"last_modified": ISODate("2015-05-08T07:10:11.250Z")},
        {...}
    ]
}
```

And I need to refresh last_modified field of document by finding max last_updated value of its services:

```
>db.documents.find().map(function(d){
    db.documents.update(
        {_id: d._id},
        {$set: {last_updated: Math.max(d.services.last_updated)}}
    )
})
Tue Aug 25 16:01:20.536 TypeError: Cannot read property 'last_modified' of undefined
```

How can I access and aggregate property of subdocument in array?

Comment: Should not have been closed since most of the point here is "how to get the maximum value from the array" and not referencing another property. The question clearly has the approach to the former incorrect.

Comment: Main goal of this question is how to aggregate values of objects array in document. I have not found such question even without answers.

Comment: Agreed. Unfortunately a gold badged member here has abused their powers and failed to read your question. Would love to inform you of how to do it correctly, however the hold on the question prevents further answers. Just cross your fingers and hope that re-open votes show more wisdom than the user here who placed the hold.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic process here is that you need to get the maximum sorted date from the array and obtain the value from there. Of course you need a loop, and you cannot access a value of a document directly in an update statement. So you need to read it first, but [Bulk](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/Bulk/) operations help here:

```js
var bulk = db.documents.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.documents.find().forEach(function(doc) {
  var last_modified = doc.services.sort(function(a,b) {
    return a.last_modified < b.last_modified;
  }).slice(-1)[0].last_modified;

  bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
    "$set": { "last_modified": last_modified }
  });
  count++;

  if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
    bulk.execute();
    bulk = db.documents.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
  }

});

if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
  bulk.execute();
```

Better yet, consider sorting the array itself on addition of new items. This is basically done with the the [**`$sort`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/sort/) modifier to [**`$push`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/update/push/)

```js
 db.documents.update(
     { "_id": id },
     { "$push": { 
         "services": {
             "$each": [{ "last_modified": date }],
             "$sort": { "last_modified": 1 }
     }}
)
```

Or even forget the `$sort` since all array values are appended to the end anyway, unless you tell the operation to to otherwise.

Then you can basically shorten the procedure using [**`$slice`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/v3.0/reference/operator/projection/slice/).

```js
var bulk = db.documents.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.documents.find(
    {},
    { 
        "last_modified": { "$slice": -1}
    }
).forEach(function(doc) {

  bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
    "$set": { "last_modified": doc.last_modified[0] }
  });
  count++;

  if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
    bulk.execute();
    bulk = db.documents.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
  }

});

if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
  bulk.execute();
```

The aggregation framework could be used here, but is really not necessary considering how simple it is to just get the maximum date value from the object per document anyway.

```js
var bulk = db.documents.initializeOrderedBulkOp(),
    count = 0;

db.documents.aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$services" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": "$_id",
        "last_modified": { "$max": "$services.last_modified" }
    }}
]).forEach(function(doc) {

  bulk.find({ "_id": doc._id }).updateOne({
    "$set": { "last_modified": doc.last_modified }
  });
  count++;

  if ( count % 1000 == 0 ) {
    bulk.execute();
    bulk = db.documents.initializeOrderedBulkOp();
  }

});

if ( count % 1000 != 0 )
  bulk.execute();
```

And because of the usage of [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) this actually comes at a much greater cost than is necessary.